# How to automatically trim a URL up to a certain length measured from the right?

Tags: urls

### Current condition

A long URL makes a bad look as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!50},
    breaklines=true,
}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\InputCode#1#2{%
\lstinputlisting[caption=\href{#2}{#2}]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\minipage{0.5\linewidth}
\InputCode{\jobname.tex}{http://www.oakfurniturehouse.co.uk/userfiles/image/3B4K1820.jpg}
\endminipage

\end{document}
```

### Expected Result

I want to trim the left part up to a certain length measured from the right as follows. The trimmed part will be replaced by `...`.

[image]

How to do this automatically because the `minipage` width can vary throughout my document.

Comment: Do you want an option like `gobbleleft` or a simple optional argument which required a number?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I don't understand well your question. I just need the untrimmed part of the URL occupies in the available space of `\linewidth-2\sideoffset` where `\sideoffset` is used to make the URL look centered rather than fully justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with some side notes:

- do not use `\def` -- In the frontend it's more comfortable to use `xparse`.
- Combinations like `\minipage` --- `\endminipage` should be avoided. Use `\begin{minipage}` --- `\end{minipage}`.

---

Here a suggestion using the benefits of expl3. The following mechanism is used:

1. Save the url in a `hbox` and compare the with of the box with the required width.
2. If the width of the url is too long the url will be saved as a token list. Now the first token of the list will be removed and the result will be saved inside a hbox. And now see 1.

Here The code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!50},
    breaklines=true,
}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newlength\sideoffset
\setlength\sideoffset{2cm}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \InputCode { m m }
 {
    \lstinputlisting
      [caption=\href{#2}{
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #2 }
        \dim_compare:nNnTF
            { \linewidth - 2\sideoffset} > { \box_wd:N  \l_tmpa_box  }
            {%TRUE
                 #2        
            }
            {%FALSE
             \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_tail:n { #2 } }
             \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
             \dim_while_do:nNnn { \box_wd:N  \l_tmpa_box } >  { \linewidth - 2\sideoffset}
               {
                 \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_tail:N  \l_tmpa_tl  } 
                \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \tl_use:N  \l_tmpa_tl  }
               }
            \ldots   \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl 
          }
      }
      ] 
      {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\InputCode{\jobname.tex}{http://www.oakfurniturehouse.co.uk/userfiles/image/3B4K1820.jpg}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```